# UPSERT MYSQL command with JDBC and JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I want to be able to insert a row and if the primary key is seen to already exist it will just update the row instead to what the user wants. I am able to write the UPSERT command but it is giving me a Null pointer error. I'm not sure why.

This is my code:

```
  public PreparedStatement updateStudent(String studentId, String studentName, String sex, java.util.Date birthDate, double gpa) throws SQLException
    {
        // TODO: Use a PreparedStatement and return it at the end of the method
        java.sql.Date sd = new java.sql.Date(birthDate.getTime());

        String sql = "INSERT INTO student (sid, sname, sex, birthDate, gpa)
                      VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    \n" +
                      "sname=?, sex=?, birthDate=?, gpa=?";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, studentId);
        pstmt.setString(2, studentName);
        pstmt.setString(3, sex);
        pstmt.setDate(4, sd);
        pstmt.setDouble(5, gpa);
        pstmt.setString(6, studentName);
        pstmt.setString(7, sex);
        pstmt.setDate(8, sd);
        pstmt.setDouble(9, gpa);
        int row = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        return pstmt;
    }
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Updating student 00567454:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EnrollJDBC.updateStudent(EnrollJDBC.java:349)
    at EnrollJDBC.main(EnrollJDBC.java:85)
```

Comment: Have you used debugger to check what variable is null?

Comment: Why the `\n` inside this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    \n`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that birthDate was null and the conversion of java.util.Date to java.sql.Date does not take null. So i had to add an if else statement if the birthDate was null